# How can I put numbers In several TextViews?

Tags: android, button, textview

Hey I have gridview buttons like keyboard with green light if I click on one of them turns to red anyways and I have 4 TextViews so I want when I press a number text it on textview1 then second number goes to txt2 the third to txt3 the fourth to txt4 but the txt4 must be changeable if I pressed on another number automatically changes and it is important that I can't use same number for example in txt1 I pressed number 1 the button goes red so I can't use it in txt2,3,4 Until I delete it from txt1 look at my picture and if someone want the code i'm happy to put it

(and how automatically jumps to the next textview after one number)
[image]

MainActivity.java this helps me with edit text I want it for TextView

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n4);
    b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n5);
    b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n6);
    b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n7);
    b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n8);
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n9);
    b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n0);
    ent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    clr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Clear);
    buttonEffect(b0);
    buttonEffect(b1);
    buttonEffect(b2);
    buttonEffect(b3);
    buttonEffect(b4);
    buttonEffect(b5);
    buttonEffect(b6);
    buttonEffect(b7);
    buttonEffect(b8);
    buttonEffect(b9);




/*    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    clr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*/

        //for default keyboard don't appear
    editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            clr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });





    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            textContainer = s.toString();
            prevLength = s.length();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            length = s.length();
            if (!textContainer.isEmpty()) {
                if (s.length() > 1) {
                    if (prevLength < length) {
                        if (!textContainer.contains(s.toString().subSequence(length - 1, length))) {
                            length = s.length();
                        } else {
                            editText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                textContainer = s.toString();
            }


        }
    });




    b0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "0"));
            b0.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String zero = "0";
                txt1.setText(zero);

        }
    });


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "1"));
            b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));

            String one = "1";
        txt1.setText(one);

        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "2"));
            b2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String two = "2";
            txt1.setText(two);

        }
    });


    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "3"));
            b3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String three = "3";
            txt1.setText(three);

        }
    });


    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "4"));
            b4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String four = "4";
            txt1.setText(four);

        }
    });


    b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "5"));
            b5.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String five = "5";
            txt1.setText(five);

        }
    });


    b6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "6"));
            b6.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String six = "6";
            txt1.setText(six);

        }
    });


    b7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "7"));
            b7.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String seven = "7";
            txt1.setText(seven);

        }
    });


    b8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "8"));
            b8.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String eight = "8";
            txt1.setText(eight);

        }
    });


    b9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getText().length(), "9"));

            b9.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            String nine = "9";
            txt1.setText(nine);
        }
    });


    ent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


    clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clr.setPressed(true);
            int length = editText.getText().length();
            if (length > 0) {
                editText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
            }


            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("0")) {
                b0.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b0.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b0.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b0.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("1")) {
                b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b1.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b1.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("2")) {
                b2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b2.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b2.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("3")) {
                b3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b3.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b3.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("4")) {
                b4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b4.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b4  .setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("5")) {
                b5.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b5.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b5.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b5.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("6")) {
                b6.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b6.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b6.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b6.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("7")) {
                b7.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b7.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b7.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b7.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("8")) {
                b8.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b8.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                b8.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b8.setEnabled(true);

            }
            if (editText.getText().toString().contains("9")) {
                b9.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
                b9.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{

                b9.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
                b9.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });


}

public static void buttonEffect(View button){
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0ffffff, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    clr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    clr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return    super.onTouchEvent(event);

}
```

xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mike.keyboardtest.MainActivity">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#112"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="clear"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_enter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:text="enter"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:text="9"

            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: create array for textview and set as per position

Comment: /can u help me with that

Comment: you have to use selector for the color chnge

Comment: wait i will put my full code

Comment: How do you want to delete the the content of a TextView? Is it specific or backwards clear? For ex. if press clear and TexView 1 ,2,3 contain some data TextView 3 must be cleared?

Comment: check my code and no just like i said 1-2-3-4 will contain another numbers i want that the user can't enter same number in any textview if he putted in txt1 the button goes red (disable) and can't use it again except if he deleted it (backspace)

Comment: the user enters first number then jumps to the second txt2 enters it then the third and forth when he click backspace the forth deleted then the third then second, first

Comment: Are you trying to input 4-number unique PIN from the user?

Comment: It's a game i want 4 free slots the user enters the number from left to right and he can't use the same number until he backspace the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For brevity, I've only chosen five buttons.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] values = new String[]{" ", " ", " ", " "};
    TextView textView[] = new TextView[4];
    int size = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        textView[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
        textView[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_2);
        textView[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_3);
        textView[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_4);
        // bind your buttons views here
        // for ex:
        button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0);
        // so on up to button 9
        // ...
        //Also bind views for Clear button and enter
    }

    // This method is set statically in xml file check below
        public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_0:
                setText(0);
                button0.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case R.id.button_1:
                setText(1);
                button1.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case R.id.button_2:
                setText(2);
                button2.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case R.id.button_3:
                setText(3);
                button3.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case R.id.button_4:
                setText(4);
                button4.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case R.id.button_clear:
                if (size == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                String numberToCleared = values[size - 1];
                clearButton(Integer.parseInt(numberToCleared));
                size--;
                values[size] = " ";
                bindText();
                break;
            case R.id.button_enter:
                //do what you want to do here
                break;
        }
    }

    private void clearButton(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 0:
                button0.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case 1:
                button1.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                button2.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                button3.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case 4:
                button4.setEnabled(true);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void bindText() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            textView[i].setText(values[i]);
        }
    }

    public void setText(int number) {
        if (size == 4) {
            clearButton(Integer.parseInt(values[3]));
            size--;
        }
        values[size] = String.valueOf(number);
        size++;
        bindText();
    }
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_1"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_2"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_4"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="2">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="0"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="4"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Clear"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_enter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Enter"/>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**button_selector.xml** Place this in your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green"/>
</selector>
```

**Logic (as OP asked for it)**
The `values` array stores the numbers that are supposed to be displayed in TextViews.

When a button is pressed the values array is updated in the setText() method.

When clear is pressed this is what happens -

```
        if (size == 0) {
            return;  // if size is 0 do nothing.
        }
        String numberToCleared = values[size - 1];
        //You've to clear the button color. So, get the last value in array
        //and send it to clearButton() function.
        clearButton(Integer.parseInt(numberToCleared));
        //remove the number from values array and decrement size
        size--; 
        values[size] = " ";
        bindText();
        break;
```

Comment: thanks nice work but there is wrong when i press number 6 number 7 goes red and then when i click clear it doesn't change

Comment: y it's not working with design i putted every id like yours but i putted my xml check my post

Comment: @CJS Replace everything. MainActivity, activity_main.xml also . Also, the button_selector file.

Comment: @CJS Also, note that I've added onClick attribute to each of the buttons in the layout.xml.

Comment: I will try my design as u say

Comment: still can't press on any button with my design check my updated xml

Comment: when i'm gonna use onclick method i guess the problem there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125329/discussion-between-gurupad-mamadapur-and-cjs).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959517/how-can-i-disable-the-changable-textview-and-click-on-it-reenable-the-button

Answer (score 1):

```
int click = 0;
TextView tv [] = new TextView[4];
```

onCreate:

```
    tv[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    tv[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
```

onClick:

```
    if(click <= 3) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.n1:
                number  = "1";
                clickCount.add(0);
                btn[0].setEnabled(false);
            break;
        }
        setTv(number, click);
        click++;
    }
```

metod:

```
public void setTv(String str, int click){

    switch (click){
        case 0:
            tv[0].setText(str);
            break;

        case 1:
            tv[1].setText(str);
            break;
        case 2:
            tv[2].setText(str);
            break;
        case 3:
            tv[3].setText(str);
            break;

    }
}
```

delete button in:

```
    if(click != 0) {
       tv[--click].setText("");
    }
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#112"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="clear"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/Clear" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="enter"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/tvstroke"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/tvstroke"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tvstroke"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tvstroke"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView stroke:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

int click = 0;
TextView tvKeyBoard;
TextView tv [] = new TextView[4];

Button btn[] = new Button[10];
ArrayList<Integer> clickCount = new ArrayList<>();

String fullNamber = "";

Button del, clear;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Clear);

    tv[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    tv[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);

    btn[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n1);
    btn[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n2);
    btn[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n3);
    btn[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n4);
    btn[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n5);
    btn[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n6);
    btn[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n7);
    btn[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n8);
    btn[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n9);
    btn[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n0);

    for (Button b : btn){
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(clickCount.size() != 0) {
                btn[clickCount.get(clickCount.size()-1)].setEnabled(true);
                clickCount.remove(clickCount.size()-1);
            }

            if(click != 0) {
                tv[--click].setText("");
            }

        }
    });

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < clickCount.size(); i++ ){
                btn[clickCount.get(i)].setEnabled(true);
            }
            clickCount.clear();
        }
    });






}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String number = "";

 if(click <= 3) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.n1:
            number  = "1";
            clickCount.add(0);
            btn[0].setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case R.id.n2:
            number  = "2";
            clickCount.add(1);
            btn[1].setEnabled(false);
            break;

        case R.id.n3:
            number  = "3";
            clickCount.add(2);
            btn[2].setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case R.id.n4:
            number  = "4";
            clickCount.add(3);
            btn[3].setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case R.id.n5:
            number  = "5";
            clickCount.add(4);
            btn[4].setEnabled(false);
            break;

        case R.id.n6:
            number  = "6";
            clickCount.add(5);
            btn[5].setEnabled(false);
            break;

        case R.id.n7:
            number  = "7";
            clickCount.add(6);
            btn[6].setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case R.id.n8:
            number  = "8";
            clickCount.add(7);
            btn[7].setEnabled(false);
            break;

        case R.id.n9:
            number  = "9";
            clickCount.add(8);
            btn[8].setEnabled(false);
            break;

        case R.id.n0:
            number  = "0";
            clickCount.add(9);
            btn[9].setEnabled(false);
            break;


    }


        setTv(number, click);
        click++;
    }



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    if(del.isEnabled()){
        for (Button b : btn){
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        del.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        clear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else
        super.onBackPressed();

}

public void setTv(String str, int count){

    switch (count){
        case 0:
            tv[0].setText(str);
            break;

        case 1:
            tv[1].setText(str);
            break;
        case 2:
            tv[2].setText(str);
            break;
        case 3:
            tv[3].setText(str);
            break;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: i'm trying can u put ur full code here with this editions

Comment: I added MainActivity

Comment: if i press number 0 disable number 9 on row before same thing if i pess 1 disable 0 :O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125330/discussion-between---and-cjs).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959517/how-can-i-disable-the-changable-textview-and-click-on-it-reenable-the-button