# how can I disable the changable TextView and click on it reenable the button?

Tags: android, button, textview

Hey I have a button keyboards with green picture if the user press on it  disable it(red color) and print it on the text view I have 4 textview so step by step the 4 text view fill the last textview doesn't stand and it's own number its changes every time I press on another enable number how can i disable this
and I want when I click on every textview to delete the number in it and reenable the number that was in it and for example i choose second txt2 and i cleared it by click on it by pressing on a number goes automatically on the second textview
take a look at the picture

[image]

```
Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;
Button b7;
Button b8;
Button b9;
Button b0;
Button ent;
Button clr;
String[] values = new String[]{" ", " ", " ", " "};
TextView textView[] = new TextView[4];
int size = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    textView[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_2);
    textView[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_3);
    textView[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_4);



    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);
    b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_6);
    b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_7);
    b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_8);
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_9);
    b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0);
    ent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
    clr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
    buttonEffect(b0);
    buttonEffect(b1);
    buttonEffect(b2);
    buttonEffect(b3);
    buttonEffect(b4);
    buttonEffect(b5);
    buttonEffect(b6);
    buttonEffect(b7);
    buttonEffect(b8);
    buttonEffect(b9);
    buttonEffect(clr);
    buttonEffect(ent);

}




public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_0:
            setText(0);
            b0.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b0.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_1:

            setText(1);
            b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b1.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            setText(2);
            b2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b2.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_3:
            setText(3);
            b3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b3.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_4:
            setText(4);
            b4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b4.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_5:
            setText(5);
            b5.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b5.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_6:
            setText(6);
            b6.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b6.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_7:
            setText(7);
            b7.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b7.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_8:
            setText(8);
            b8.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b8.setEnabled(false);

            break;


        case R.id.button_9:
            setText(9);
            b9.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redww));
            b9.setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.button_clear:
            if (size == 0) {
                return;
            }
            String numberToCleared = values[size - 1];
            clearButton(Integer.parseInt(numberToCleared));
            size--;
            values[size] = " ";
            bindText();
            break;
        case R.id.button_enter:
            break;
    }
}

private void clearButton(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 0 : b0.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b0.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        case 1 : b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b1.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 2 : b2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b2.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 3 : b3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b3.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 4 : b4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b4.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 5 : b5.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b5.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 6 : b6.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b6.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 7 : b7.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b7.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 8 : b8.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b8.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case 9 : b9.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenww));
            b9.setEnabled(true);

            break;
    }
}

public void bindText() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        textView[i].setText(values[i]);
    }

}

public void setText(int number) {
    if (size == 4) {
        clearButton(Integer.parseInt(values[3]));
        size--;
    }
    values[size] = String.valueOf(number);
    size++;
    bindText();
}



public static void buttonEffect(View button){
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0ffffff, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });



}
```

xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#112"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="clear"
            android:onClick="onClick"

            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_4"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_5"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_6"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_enter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="enter"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.40">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_7"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_8"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_9"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_0"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:freezesText="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greenww"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How about some code? What did you try so far?

Comment: "the last textview doesn't stand" that's because you accept clicks also for size >= 4 and even reduce the size in setText() to show the new value. For the rest: take a look at SparseIntArray. It lets you map e.g. resource id (key) to number (value)

Comment: i changed the size now i have problem with the last textview when i click on a number the app crushes

Comment: I can't know what you changed - I thought of some check like `if (size >= 4) return;` in the button onClickLlistener in cases where a number was clicked (in all cases where id != R.id.button_enter && id != button_clear). Simply don't react to clicks, this will not cause a crash.

Comment: and I need some focus on textview when i click on it delete the number and enable the button for example number 5 so i can put another number on that field

Comment: Well, TextView is a kind of View, so you can set a View.OnClickListener for your TextViews just like you do it for a Button.

Comment: I tried that I putted gettext.tostring then if (a=='0') enable the 0 button and change the color when I enter a number in it that wont disable that number and the number 0 are unuseable on other fields

Comment: it writes just in the textview that I pressed even if clear everything

Comment: What should happen if there are two free TextViews and I click a green number? Should the number go into the TextView with the lowest index or should it go into the TextView which was the last to be cleared (if user cleared any TextView)?

Comment: And one more thing: you have to somehow keep track of free TextViews and filled TextViews. Sorry but I simply don't have the time to rewrite your code (and I would change more than half of it. Main problem: size doesn't tell me much if TextView values can be erased randomly instead of being cleared only from the top). That's why I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: yes with the lower index and what can I do this is my task at my job :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971560/how-to-clear-textview-with-a-click-and-enable-the-disabled-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sparse...Array`s are very useful because they can act as a kind of `Map` while avoiding autoboxing  if you're working with primitive data types. For further information regarding available methods, please take a look at the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html).

The following code uses `SparseIntArray` in two places: for `Button`s, we want to map the resource id to the number of each `Button`.

For `TextView`s, we need to keep track of their state: are they filled, and if so, with which number? So we use a `SparseIntArray` only for filled `TextView`s. The indices from **textView** are the keys and the numbers are the values.

The `Activity` will handle clicks on `Button`s as well as `TextView`s. The **values** array is no longer necessary, the same goes for **size**.

So here's the entire `Activity` code - enjoy :)

```
private static final String EMPTY = " ";

private TextView textView[] = new TextView[4];

private SparseIntArray mapOfButtons,  // map id to number
        mapOfFilledTextViews;         // map array index to value if TextView is filled

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a8__button_on_touch_and_on_click);

    initMaps();

    textView[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    textView[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_2);
    textView[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_3);
    textView[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_4);

    for (TextView tv: textView)
    {
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    Button b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);
    Button b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_6);
    Button b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_7);
    Button b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_8);
    Button b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_9);
    Button b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0);
    Button ent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
    Button clr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_clear);

    buttonEffect(b0);
    buttonEffect(b1);
    buttonEffect(b2);
    buttonEffect(b3);
    buttonEffect(b4);
    buttonEffect(b5);
    buttonEffect(b6);
    buttonEffect(b7);
    buttonEffect(b8);
    buttonEffect(b9);
    buttonEffect(clr);
    buttonEffect(ent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();

    if (v instanceof Button)
    {
        if (mapOfButtons.indexOfKey(id) < 0)
        { // so this is no number button
            if (id == R.id.button_clear)
            {
                if (mapOfFilledTextViews.size() == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                // get the key = the index for 'textView'
                int indexToClear = indexOfRightmostFilledTextView();
                // get the value
                int numberToClear = mapOfFilledTextViews.get(indexToClear);
                clearButton(numberToClear);
                clearTextView(indexToClear);
                bindText();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.button_enter)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
        else // this is a number button
        {
            // only accept clicks if there is a free TextView
            if (mapOfFilledTextViews.size() == textView.length)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,
           "First clear one of the selected numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Button b = (Button)v;
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redww);
            b.setEnabled(false);

            int number = mapOfButtons.get(id);
            setText(number);
        }

    }
    else if (v instanceof TextView)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)v;
        int number = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString() );
        // 'indexOfValue()' will work because we don't have duplicate values
        int i = mapOfFilledTextViews.indexOfValue(number);
        int key = mapOfFilledTextViews.keyAt(i);
        clearButton(number);
        clearTextView(key);
        bindText();
    }
}

private static void buttonEffect(View button)
{
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0ffffff, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void initMaps()
{
    // empty in the beginning:
    mapOfFilledTextViews = new SparseIntArray(4);

    mapOfButtons = new SparseIntArray(10);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_0, 0);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_1, 1);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_2, 2);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_3, 3);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_4, 4);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_5, 5);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_6, 6);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_7, 7);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_8, 8);
    mapOfButtons.put(R.id.button_9, 9);
}

private void bindText()
{
    int value;
    int len = textView.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        value = mapOfFilledTextViews.get(i, -1);
        textView[i].setText(value >= 0 ? String.valueOf(value) : EMPTY);
    }
}

private void setText(int number)
{
    if (mapOfFilledTextViews.size() >= textView.length)
    {
        // this should not happen if we check the number
        // of free TextViews in onClick()
        return;
    }

    int index = indexOfLowestFreeTextView();
    mapOfFilledTextViews.put(index, number);
    bindText();
}

private void clearButton(int number)
{
    // get the first (in our case only) index with valueAt(index) == number
    int index = mapOfButtons.indexOfValue(number);

    if (index < 0) // this value does not exist
    {
        // this should not happen!
        // so maybe throw a RuntimeException
        return;
    }

    int id = mapOfButtons.keyAt(index);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(id);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenww);
    b.setEnabled(true);
}

private void clearTextView(int index)
{
    // remove entry as this TextView is no longer filled
    mapOfFilledTextViews.delete(index);
}

/**
 *
 * @return index (for use with 'textView') if there are filled TextViews, else -1
 */
private int indexOfRightmostFilledTextView()
{
    int size = mapOfFilledTextViews.size();
    int maxKey = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int iTemp = mapOfFilledTextViews.keyAt(i);
        if (iTemp > maxKey )
        {
            maxKey = iTemp;
        }
    }
    return maxKey;
}

/**
 * Get index of leftmost (lowest) free TextView
 * @return index for use with 'textView'. 
 * If all TextViews are filled, return textView.length
 */
private int indexOfLowestFreeTextView()
{
    int lowestIndex = textView.length;
    // this assumes the TextViews are sorted from left to right in the textView array
    for (int key = 0; key < textView.length; key++)
    {
        if (mapOfFilledTextViews.indexOfKey(key) < 0)
        {
            lowestIndex = key;
            break;
        }
    }
    return lowestIndex;
}
```

Comment: @CJS - took me some time to write it down, but I've learned a lot from code snippets on this site and this was an oppportunity to give something back. Happy coding!